# Unit Test for getOrderByIncrementId question

Tags: magento2, unit-tests

I've started with writing and figure out unit testing in Magento 2. I want to write a test case for getting an order by the increment id.

**This is my function which I want to write a test for:**

```
 /**
 * @param $incrementId
 * @return false|OrderInterface
 */
public function getOrderByIncrementId($incrementId)
{
    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter(
        OrderInterface::INCREMENT_ID,
        $incrementId
    )->create();

    $result = $this->orderRepo->getList($searchCriteria);

    if (empty($result->getItems())) {
        throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('No such order.'));
    }

    $orders = $result->getItems();

    return reset($orders);
}
```

I am using the `Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface` and the `Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder` for it.

Now I wrote the following test, created mocks for the classes, but I can't get an actual object for the `$searchCriteria`.

**This is my setUp function:**

```
   protected function setUp(): void
{
    $this->orderInterfaceMock = $this->getMockBuilder(OrderInterface::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $this->orderSearchResultInterface = $this->getMockBuilder(OrderSearchResultInterface::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMockForAbstractClass();

    $this->orderRepositoryMock = $this->getMockBuilder(OrderRepositoryInterface::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(['getList'])
        ->getMockForAbstractClass();

    $this->searchCriteriaBuilderMock = $this->getMockBuilder(SearchCriteriaBuilder::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(['create','addFilter'])
        ->getMock();

    $this->templateContextMock = $this->getMockBuilder(Context::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $this->checkoutSessionMock = $this->getMockBuilder(CheckoutSession::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $this->orderConfigMock = $this->getMockBuilder(Config::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $this->httpContextMock = $this->getMockBuilder(HttpContext::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

     $this->object = new Success(
        $this->orderRepositoryMock,
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilderMock,
        $this->templateContextMock,
        $this->checkoutSessionMock,
        $this->orderConfigMock,
        $this->httpContextMock,
        []
    );
}
```

**And this my test case**

```
    /**
 * @param $incrementId
 * @dataProvider getIncrementIdProvider
 */
public function testGetOrderByIncrementId($incrementId)
{
    $result = $this->object->getOrderByIncrementId($incrementId);

    $this->assertInstanceOf(OrderInterface::class, $result);
}
```

**I am getting this error:**

```
Error : Call to a member function create() on null
```

I am not sure if it's ok to just create a new object from the real Success class. I saw it somewhere else with the object manager, but as I know, this helper is only for integration tests. I can't figure it out and would appreciate your input. I am also not sure about the getList function. I added it to the OrderRepository, that should be enough, right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to mock the search criteria object also

```
$this->searchCriteriaMock = $this->createMock(SearchCriteria::class);
```

and state that the method `create` from searchCriteriaBuilderMock will return your new mock

```
$this->searchCriteriaBuilderMock->method('create')->willReturn($this->searchCriteriaMock);
```